# Running multiple spring boot microservices with Gradle

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring Boot application built using Gradle. 
We have multiple microservices as subprojects for this application.

I'm trying to run the application and all microservices using Spring Boot's bootRun task from the command line with single bootRun command.

Similarly, we would like to run some integration tests with the application and all microservices with single test command.

I appreciate for any help or pointing me some documentation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have created root build.gradle with


->  task allRun(dependsOn: ['prj1:bootRun','prj2:bootRun']) {} <-
 
but it runs the last bootRun on the dependents list (prj2:bootRun for this example)

Answer (score 6):

We decided to use gradle --parallel option.

Comment: This is ok if you have less than 4 microservices if your processor is quad core. We had 5 services and only 4 were run because there we no cores left on machine. Just as note to someone in future.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you Vajda,

Comment: @Vajda gradle also has a setting org.gradle.workers.max that lets you raise this limit.