# How does a Multi-Module Project build equate to multiple microservices? Is one the foundation for the other?

Tags: spring, maven, gradle, microservices, multi-module

I've seen multi-module Spring projects, ie, a project build composed of multiple modules.
Are these a foundation for building microservices. That is, is it usual to have microservices written as separate modules in one multi-module project? Or are microservices usually written in individual source repositories?

In sum, is multi-moduling in a project, a stepping stone to writing microservices? Or is it absolutely different things?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. It's a valid doubt going from single repository projects, to multi-module projects and throwing microservices into the mix.

Answer (score 1):

I would say microservices and multi-module projects are orthogonal. You can have microservices without multi-module project and have a monolith with multi-module project.

To have a clue what microservices are: microservices have independent deployment cycle. And consequently, they can be developed by independent teams, using different languages, different tools and so on. So taking into consideration said above: microservices most likely wouldn't be a multi-module project, but rather just independent projects.

Comment: Is it about many rest APIs for single client || many clients for 1 rest api? And is it 1 Rest Api for 2+ databases and servers? 
If microservices is about independent parts of project, why GoLang called "language for microservices" if its not about one language?

Comment: So many questions :) and it is because the topic is too broad. Rest  APIs are not characteristic of microservices, because there are technics for having single API and several  APIs in MS. Databases: yes, each MS should have it's own DB rather than sharing common one, but if you have two services with own DBs it does not mean that you have MS. I cannot say why Go is a language of MS, in my preference it isn't. And again: if your system consists of several services (applications) and you can deploy them independently - this means you have MS

Answer (score 0):

I've seen at least one example of a multi-module project where individual modules were all microservices. [prototype example](https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction2/tree/master/chapter7/prototype) from Claus Ibsen's 'Camel in Action, 2nd Ed'.
While this may be a pedagogical example, as @max-farsikov answers, you may have microservices in a multi-module project where each module is a microservice, or you may write each microservice as a separate project within its own repository.

Here's another Stackoverflow user following the [same pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33375881/434145).
And [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35684313/run-all-microservices-in-a-multi-project-gradle-build).